# how to use scrollspy in bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to html/bootstrap/css.
I'm trying to make scrollspy in a list on a website page that I'm currently working on (essentially, I'm only modifying HTML produced by R `postcards` package).

Here is my HTML code. This file uses `bootstrap 3.4.1`, I can't replicate the expected behavior with `bootstrap 4`. When I do use `<script>` with a newer version of Bootstrap (say 4.5.0) the buttons/list items (li)/links do not seem to be active anymore as I scroll through the page.

I'm not sure why this code does not run as expected using newer versions of bootstrap.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;}
      div.my-5 div {height: 500px;}
      li.active>a>button {background-color: #343a40;color: #fff;}
    </style>
    <title>Frank Hermosillo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">
      <div class="d-flex row flex-row vh-100">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column col-5 align-items-center text-center align-self-center">
          <div class="mx-auto text-center">
            <div class="p-3">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png" style="height:15rem" class="rounded">
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
              <h1>Frank Hermosillo</h1>
            </div>
            <hr style="width:60%;" />
            <div class="p-2">
              <div id="icon-list">
                <div id="myScrollspy">
                  <ul class="list-inline nav">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                      <a href="#bio">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-2">
                          Bio
                        </button>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                      <a href="#education">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark mb-2">
                          Educ
                        </button>
                      </a>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column vh-100 border-left"></div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column col px-5 align-items-center align-self-center mh-100" style="overflow-y: scroll;" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy">
          <div class="my-5" id="content">
            <div id="bio" class="section level2">
              <h2>Bio</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sodales cursus ante, ut iaculis diam euismod nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam ut felis a nisl viverra sollicitudin. Vestibulum quis elementum libero. Suspendisse pellentesque justo dui, at consectetur turpis vulputate eget. Maecenas lacus tortor, tempus eu magna ac, maximus tincidunt est. Proin vitae lacus sollicitudin, lobortis orci vitae, fringilla ex. Nullam vestibulum neque sapien, id dapibus augue molestie ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin non ante leo. Pellentesque id massa nisi. Maecenas at facilisis velit. Nunc in purus in nisi consectetur bibendum. Etiam mattis eros ante, eget suscipit lectus tincidunt sit amet. Aliquam sed suscipit dui. Nulla non tristique sem.</p>
              <p><a href="https://link-url-here.org">Link text Here</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="education" class="section level2">
              <h2>Education</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sodales cursus ante, ut iaculis diam euismod nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam ut felis a nisl viverra sollicitudin. Vestibulum quis elementum libero. Suspendisse pellentesque justo dui, at consectetur turpis vulputate eget. Maecenas lacus tortor, tempus eu magna ac, maximus tincidunt est. Proin vitae lacus sollicitudin, lobortis orci vitae, fringilla ex. Nullam vestibulum neque sapien, id dapibus augue molestie ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin non ante leo. Pellentesque id massa nisi. Maecenas at facilisis velit. Nunc in purus in nisi consectetur bibendum. Etiam mattis eros ante, eget suscipit lectus tincidunt sit amet. Aliquam sed suscipit dui. Nulla non tristique sem.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-flex min-vh-100 d-block d-lg-none d-xl-none">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
        <div class="d-flex flex-col">
          <div class="mx-auto">
            <div class="p-3 mt-3 text-center">
              <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png" style="height:15rem" class="rounded">
            </div>
            <div class="p-2 text-center">
              <h1>Frank Hermosillo</h1>
            </div>
            <hr style="width:60%;" />

            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div class="col-8 p-1 text-center">
                <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="#bio">
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action my-1 rounded">
                      Bio
                    </button>
                  </a>
                  <a href="#education">
                    <button type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action my-1 rounded">
                      Educ
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="p pt-4 px-5">
              <div id="bio" class="section level2">
                <h2>Bio</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sodales cursus ante, ut iaculis diam euismod nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam ut felis a nisl viverra sollicitudin. Vestibulum quis elementum libero. Suspendisse pellentesque justo dui, at consectetur turpis vulputate eget. Maecenas lacus tortor, tempus eu magna ac, maximus tincidunt est. Proin vitae lacus sollicitudin, lobortis orci vitae, fringilla ex. Nullam vestibulum neque sapien, id dapibus augue molestie ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin non ante leo. Pellentesque id massa nisi. Maecenas at facilisis velit. Nunc in purus in nisi consectetur bibendum. Etiam mattis eros ante, eget suscipit lectus tincidunt sit amet. Aliquam sed suscipit dui. Nulla non tristique sem.</p>
                <p><a href="https://link-url-here.org">Link text Here</a></p>
              </div>
              <div id="education" class="section level2">
                <h2>Education</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sodales cursus ante, ut iaculis diam euismod nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam ut felis a nisl viverra sollicitudin. Vestibulum quis elementum libero. Suspendisse pellentesque justo dui, at consectetur turpis vulputate eget. Maecenas lacus tortor, tempus eu magna ac, maximus tincidunt est. Proin vitae lacus sollicitudin, lobortis orci vitae, fringilla ex. Nullam vestibulum neque sapien, id dapibus augue molestie ac. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin non ante leo. Pellentesque id massa nisi. Maecenas at facilisis velit. Nunc in purus in nisi consectetur bibendum. Etiam mattis eros ante, eget suscipit lectus tincidunt sit amet. Aliquam sed suscipit dui. Nulla non tristique sem.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to add scroll spy to your site you need to add in your body tag as following: `<body> data-spy="scroll" data-target="[class of the target]" data-offset="[can be any value, depending on your likings]">`. You also need a place where the links should be updated, a navbar for example, (noted in the code above with [class of the target]). In your navbar, there should be `<a>` tags that link to the section id, for example `<a href="#[section id]">My link</a>`.
You can also add custom styling to the links when they are active like here: `a:active { //the active style }`.

Comment: It is still unclear to me why this short code works on bootstrap3.4 but not newer versions.
furthermore, I'm following the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/scrollspy/), which says that I can spy on another object rather than `body`. In my code, I'm spying on another `div`, but for some reason, it does not work as expected.